# Check credentials specified by user (login, password, role) with username, password and role given in .txt file. Check in txt by: login passwd role\n

Tags: python, passwords

```
def login():
    temp = []
    print("Login to warehouse\n")
    name = str(input("Enter a login: "))
    pas = str(input("Enter a password: "))
    role = str(input("Enter a role: "))
    if role == "admin" or role == "reworker":
        print("Role identified!\n\n")
    else:
        err("Role unidentified!\n\n")
        login()
    with open('log.txt', 'r') as fs:
        text = fs.readlines()
        for x in text:
            if name in x and pas in x and x[2] == 'admin':
                print("Admin")
            elif name in x and pas in x and x[2] == 'reworker':
                print("Worker")
            else:
                print("Incorrect credentials!\n")
```

File is:

```
mans 123 admin
mans 123 admin
Mansur 4950495 reworker
God 123 admin
hello 123 admin
ror 123 admin
```

Comment: there are several issues but `x[2]` is a single character and therefore will never be == `'admin'` because `x` is not a list but a string. Did you mean to do `x.split(' ')[2]`?

Comment: is x single character in this case?

Comment: i dont know. I want to check x for matching with user entered credentials

Comment: `x` is a string and therefore doing `x[2]` will result in a single character. You can test it by adding `print(x[2])` right after `for x in text:` just before the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote it a little and it seems to be working.

```
def login():
    temp = []
    print("Login to warehouse\n")
    name = input("Enter a login: ")
    pas = input("Enter a password: ")
    role = input("Enter a role: ")
    if role == "admin" or role == "reworker":
        print("Role identified!\n\n")
    else:
        print("Role unidentified!\n\n")
        login()
    with open('log.txt', 'r') as fs:
        text = fs.readlines()
        auth = 'Incorrect Credentials'
        for x in text:
            x = x.split() # splits line into list based on whitespace
            if name == x[0] and pas == x[1] and x[2] == 'admin':
                auth = 'Admin'
                break
            elif name == x[0] and pas == x[1] and x[2] == 'reworker':
                auth = 'Reworker'
                break
            else:
                # incorrect credentials on one line
                pass

    print(auth)
    # return auth
```

Comment: Man this is fatal too). Program checks only first line and doing well, but If i enter, for example: God 123 admin, he give me 'else' output :)

Comment: Check you capitalization.
I did and it turns out, I didn't capitalize God.

Comment: posted code below.. Eventually handled with that

Answer (score 0):

Its working

```
def login():
    print("Login to warehouse\n")
    name = input("Enter a login: ")
    pas = input("Enter a password: ")
    with open('log.txt', 'r') as R:
        tmp = []
        for i in R.readlines():
            i = i.split()
            tmp.append(i)
        for x in tmp:
            if name in x:
                if pas in x:
                    if x[2] == 'admin':
                        role = x[2]
                        print("Logged as admin!\n")
                        admin(name, role)
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Logged as worker!\n")
                        break
                else:
                    print("Incorrect password!\n") 
                    break
            else:
                pass
        print("Error: Login failed!\n")
```